# Meteor program or script that will "compile" before runtime

Tags: meteor

I'm building a site that I intend to add new content to after it's deployed, essays I write, new things I create, news stories involving me, etc.

All of this content will be added **only** by me, and it won't at all be dynamic content. I'll add it, and that will be that. For this reason, I don't want to go to the trouble of building pages into my app that will allow me to "add" or "edit" new posts or whatever. I also don't want to bother storing this content in my database. It's static content, and the database is for dynamic content. Why burden my database with requests for something I could just include with the initial app load?

What I *really* want is to write something into my app that could take a combination of content and configuration information (such as markdown files and a json config file, respectively) and compile them into templates, navigation links, javascript objects, or whatever I needed them to be. **Compile** is the operative word. I want this to operate in much the same way the `less` pre-processor does.

How do I write something that will happen only once, as the application is being compiled/bundled/deployed/etc?

**Note:** this program/process/script/whatever should also be run on any hot-code reloads or restarts, etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If its about the initial load that you want it to have this behaviour there is a package called Fast-Render (https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-fast-render) that adds data to the initial page load.

Comment: Not quite. I found an answer, `Meteor.startup()`

Comment: That is a cool package though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel dumb for not catching this, but just using [Meteor.startup](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_startup) will do the trick.

```js
// on the server
Meteor.startup(function() {
    // whatever behavior
});
```